# What are the different VMware Fusion networks used for?

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

Running VMware Fusion with Windows 11 guest on Mac Ventura host, I notice 4 virtual network interfaces on the Mac.  What are each of these used for?  I found some references to `vmnet` in the documentation, but nothing about `vmenet`.  I have the VM set to NAT mode (share with my Mac).

The guest has an address in the 192.168.11 network.

Looking around with Wireshark, it seems like `vmenet2` is used for multicast only but I don't know why it would be separated like that.

```
vmenet1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 62:c8:13:bc:94:68 
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge101: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 5e:e9:1e:d9:df:65 
    inet 192.168.11.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.11.255
    inet6 fe80::5ce9:1eff:fed9:df65%bridge101 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 31 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: vmenet2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 33 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: vmenet3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 34 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmenet2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether b6:b6:a5:3a:0b:a9 
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmenet3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether d6:62:c4:e5:cf:57 
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article:

[VMware Fusion VMNet defaults](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022264)

The default VMNet uses are the same for VMware Fusion and VMware Workstation (I use the latter).

The **Bridged** network adapter is known as **vmnet0.** In Fusion 3.x and later, it uses the vmnet-bridge and vmnet-netifup services.

The **Host-only** network adapter is known as **vmnet1**. In Fusion 3.x and later, it uses the vmnet-dhcpd service.

The **NAT** network adapter is known as **vmnet8.** In Fusion 3.x and later, it uses the vmnet-natd, vmnet-dhcpd, and vmnet-netifup services.

Other VMNet adapters like VMNet2 are custom adapters that you would have set up (that is, not default).

So look in the VMware Network Editor and see what you have set up. It should be quite clear in the Network Editor.

Comment: That article makes it sound like these are mutually exclusive, based on each VM's settings.  But I am seeing traffic on all 3 networks at once in Wireshark on the host.  My interfaces are numbered 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,8.  And they are named with an extra E `vmenet`

Comment: The answer is how VMware default network settings have been done the same for many years (a couple of decades) .  Your settings are done by you or someone setting up your computer.  So only you know what they are for. As a guess, they are kind of NAT connection.